# Airflow 1.10.10 Task is in Success status but eventually will be in 'removed' state and disappears in Graph View

Tags: airflow

I am currently facing this issue with dynamically generated tasks. The created tasks uses KubernetesPodOperators. The task executes but after sometime it disappears in Graph View.
I can see the task instance details(from the link of the task) for few minutes but will eventually disappears too. Here's the info I got from the task details:

In Task Instance Details:

```
   Dependency: Dagrun Running
   Reason: Task instance's dagrun was not in the 'running' state but in the state 'success'.

   Dependency: Task Instance State
   Reason: Task is in the 'removed' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
```

Anybody facing such issue? I saw this bug filed and seem similar: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-7116

Also another thing I notice is the DAG owner (dag table owner field) gets empty.

Comment: This issue seems to happen with dynamic tasks in DAGs. I retrieve a list of records from DB using PostgresHook. Then I loop to the records and create tasks. So the number of tasks can vary. Airflow DAGs needs to build the tasks and since the number of records can vary(could be empty), the tasks generated are based on the last number of tasks. So the previous task might not show up. To work around this, I created fixed number of tasks and based on the data, I can skip execute or skip the task (raise AirflowSkipException)